# What's the source for the allusion of 'mere vessels of happiness'?

Tags: allusions

Source: Benatar, David. [*Better Never to Have Been*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0199549265) (2008 1 edn). pp. 36 Bottom - 37 Top.

> The judgements supported by the asymmetry of [(3) and (4)](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/52303/8572) are
>   not universally shared. For example, positive utilitarians—who
>   are interested not only in minimizing pain but also in maximizing
>   pleasure—would tend to lament the absence of additional possible
>   pleasure even if there were nobody deprived of that pleasure.
>   On their view, there *is* a duty to bring people into existence if
>   that would increase happiness. This is not to say that all positive
>   utilitarians *must* reject the view about the asymmetry of (3) and
>   (4). Positive utilitarians who are sympathetic to the asymmetry
>   could draw a distinction between (i) promoting the happiness of
>   people (that exist, or will exist independently of one’s choices) and
>   (ii) increasing happiness by making people. This is the now famous
>   distinction between (i) making people happy and (ii) making happy
>   people. Positive utilitarians who draw this distinction could then,
>
> consistent with positive utilitarianism, judge only (i) to be a
>   requirement of morality. This is the preferable version of positive
>   utilitarianism. Taking (ii) also to be a requirement of morality
>   mistakenly assumes that the value of happiness is primary and the
>   value of persons is derivative from this. However, it is not the case
>   that people are valuable because they add extra happiness. Instead
>   extra happiness is valuable because it is good for people—because
>   it makes people’s lives go better. To think otherwise is to think
>   that people are mere means to the production of happiness. **Or,
>   to use another famous image, it is to treat persons as mere vessels
>   of happiness. But unlike a mere vessel**, which is indifferent to how
>   much of a valued substance it contains, a person cares about how
>   much happiness he has.

Comment: Benatar is [head of Bioethics at the University of Cape Town](http://www.philosophy.uct.ac.za/philosophy/staff/benatar), so you could contact him directly as described on the linked page.

Comment: @GarethRees I did email him, but he tactfully replied that he lacks time to answer questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the source of the allusion.  It might be one of these:

This appears in Chapter II of [*Tess of the D'Urbervilles*](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/110/110-h/110-h.htm):

> Tess Durbeyfield at this time of her life was a mere vessel of emotion untinctured by experience.

And [Confucius](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/46389/46389-h/46389-h.htm) (on pp. 71 and 94 of the book linked here) is said to have said,

> Tzŭ Kung asked, saying: What, Sir, is your opinion of me?—I would liken you, Tz‘ŭ, replied the Master, to a vessel limited in its function.—What sort of vessel? asked Tzŭ Kung.—A richly ornamented sacrificial vessel, was the reply.

and

> The higher type of man is not like a vessel which is designed for some Special use.

In general "vessel" can mean a ship or boat, or a container for liquids.  I suppose your quotation takes it in the latter sense.

Answer (score 2):

I am not convinced that "mere vessels of happiness" is in fact a "famous image" as claimed by Benatar. If it were famous then I would expect to be able to find more instances of the image using tools like Google Book Search or Google Scholar, but I have been unable to do so.

The closest that I have been able to find is in Singer (1981):

> But pure Classical Utilitarianism treats people as **replaceable vessels containing quantities of happiness**, so that it is all right to kill a person if one can replace her with another person who will be just as happy, and there are no side-effects.

But this is not the same image! Singer's objection is about treating people as *replaceable* vessels (that is, aggregation of utility does not take into account the separation of persons), but Benatar's objection is about treating people as *mere* vessels (that is, as means rather than ends).

So I would have to put [citation needed] on Benatar's claim.

#### Reference

- Peter Singer (1981). "[Reply to Dr Harris](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1468-0149.1981.tb01024.x)". *Analytic Philosophy* 22:4, pp. 198–200.

Comment: So maybe its somewhere in J.S.Mill or J.Bentham, and is well-known to fellow scholars of Utilitarianism?  But not to the general public? ("If you have to ask, you can't afford it" morphs to "if you need a citation you won't understand it"?)

Comment: I did look in both Mill and Bentham, also Sidgwick, Moore, Gauthier, Rawls, & Nozick. Maybe Benatar's objection is in there somewhere, but not his "famous image".